# r rename columns that don't have a certain name

Tags: r, for-loop, rename

I want to rename all columns EXCEPT a few that I want to specify by name. The problem here is that the columns are in different order across datasets, and I want a universal code.

```
#data is a list of the data.tables I want to rename
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
temp <- data[i]
setkeyv(get(temp), c("HDDSN","ENDDATE"))
#trying to create a list of all columns that are NOT named "some name"
orig.names <- which(names(get(temp))!=c("HDDSN","ENDDATE","PHEADNO"))
#I want to rename the columns in the format of "p+tablename+original names"
new.names <- paste(paste("p",substring(temp,5,13), sep=""), get(temp)[orig.names], sep=".")
setnames(get(temp), orig.names, new.names)
}
```

It's the creation of the orig.names object that is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

How about the below code? It will allow you to rename a column without having to worry about its relative position within a dataframe. You can consider running this after running your iterative re-naming for-loop.

```
names(dataframe)[names(dataframe)=="oldname"] <- "newname"
```